# Windows phone Argument Exception

Tags: windows-phone-8

I Got Error as "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code"

```
    void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
    {
        int pointsNumber = e.GetTouchPoints(img1).Count; \\ I got the Exception in this Line
        TouchPointCollection pointCollection = e.GetTouchPoints(img1);

        for (int i = 0; i < pointsNumber; i++)
        {
            if (pointCollection[i].Action == TouchAction.Down)
            {
                preXArray[i] = pointCollection[i].Position.X;
                preYArray[i] = pointCollection[i].Position.Y;
            }
            if (pointCollection[i].Action == TouchAction.Move)
            {
                line = new Line();

                line.X1 = preXArray[i];
                line.Y1 = preYArray[i];
                line.X2 = pointCollection[i].Position.X;
                line.Y2 = pointCollection[i].Position.Y;

                line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

                line.StrokeStartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
                line.StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
                line.StrokeThickness = 20;
                img1.Children.Add(line);

                preXArray[i] = pointCollection[i].Position.X;
                preYArray[i] = pointCollection[i].Position.Y;
            }
        }
    }
```

How to Handle This Exception in Windows Phone 8

Answer (score 0):

You need a try catch with catch blocks like this...

```
 try { ... }
   catch(System.ArgumentNullException ane) { ... }
   catch(System.NotSupportedException nse) { ... }
   catch(System.IO.PathTooLongException ple) { ... }
   catch(System.IO.SecurityException se) { ... }
   catch(System.ArgumentException ae) { ... }
```

Make sure your 'System.ArgumentException' is your last catch. Use the 4 above if need be, you might not need path handler...

Comment: I already do with catch(System.ArgumentException ae) { throw(ae)} but app become very slow. what to do

Comment: focus on making sure your 'img1' var is never null and put condition into GetTouchPoints() to where it always returns a count. you'll then never have to worry about catching a sys exception..